# Why is area intersection is not empty when it should be?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a bullet that hits player on intersection. At some reason, it deals damage when it is not even close  :(

The following code checks whether the bullet hits player:

```
Area a = new Area(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(r, getX() + getWidth() / 2, getY() + getHeight() / 2)
        .createTransformedShape(new Rectangle(getX() + (int)(getWidth()-sx) / 2, getY() + (int)(getHeight()-sy) / 2, (int)sx, (int)sy)));
a.intersect(new Area(Root.game.player.hitbox));
if (!a.isEmpty())
    hit(Root.game.player);
```

Method "hit()" deals damage to player and graduately decreases bullet size.

Hitbox of the player is placed properly.

Required "hitbox" of the bullet is that graphics' content:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    AffineTransform a = g2.getTransform();
    a.rotate(Math.toRadians(r), getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
    int sx = (int)Math.round(this.sx), sy = (int)Math.round(this.sy);
    g2.setTransform(a);
    int dx = (getWidth()-sx) / 2, dy = (getHeight()-sy) / 2;
    g2.setPaint(new RadialGradientPaint(new Rectangle(sx / 6 + dx, sy / 6 + dy, Math.max(1, sx * 2 / 3), Math.max(1, sy * 2 / 3)), new float[]{0, 1}, new Color[]{Color.CYAN, new Color(0, 255, 255, 0)}, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE));
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(sy / 5, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
    g2.drawRect(sx / 3 + dx, sy / 3 + dy, sx / 3, sy / 3);
    g2.setPaint(new RadialGradientPaint(new Rectangle(sx / 6 + dx, sy / 6 + dy, Math.max(1, sx * 2 / 3), Math.max(1, sy * 2 / 3)), new float[]{0, 1}, new Color[]{c, Color.BLUE}, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE));
    g2.fillRoundRect(sx / 3 + dx, sy / 3 + dy, sx / 3, sy / 3, sx / 20, sy / 15);
}
```

Comment: You should be overriding the `paintComponent` method of a `JPanel`.  You should also be using logical hit boxes and bullets.  Your painting code should only paint.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, I have posted paint code just to explain, what I expect from the code above (first multiline snippet), that represents logical hitbox. I ask community to tell me how to fix it. 
Sorry for my English & possible misunderstanding.

Comment: I believe what they're suggesting is rather than working with raw `Area`, `Graphics2D`, etc objects, you should re-use or make your own `BoundingBox` (e.g. `Hitbox` or `AxisAlignedBB`) `Entity`, and other classes. Keep those objects up-to-date at runtime, then make use of the classes when rendering to determine what `Area` and `Graphics2D` objects need to be put where.

Answer (score 0):

I have just understood, what was the problem.

`AffineTransform.getRotateInstance()` accepts angle in radians, and the variable `r` is angle in degrees. The solution is pretty simple - `Math.toRadians()`.